# mod-wsgi error Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Apache 2.4.10 and mod-wsgi 4.4 environments.

Below is apache error log file :

```
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360055 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425] mod_wsgi (pid=3729): Target WSGI script '/home/service/was/test/test_app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360060 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425] mod_wsgi (pid=3729): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/service/was/test/test_app.wsgi'.
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360067 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360075 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425]   File "/home/service/was/test/test_app.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360119 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425]     from test_app import app as application
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360125 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425]   File "/home/service/was/test/test_app.py", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360141 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425]     from flask import Flask
[Wed Nov 02 11:15:21.360158 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3729:tid 140033629607680] [remote 10.10.200.99:7425] ImportError: No module named flask
```

And I set `httpd-virtualhost.conf`:

```
Listen 10003
<VirtualHost *:10003>

    # mod_wsgi global settings
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}

    ErrorLog "|/usr/local/server/apache/bin/rotatelogs /home/log/apache/error-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400 +540"
    TransferLog "|/usr/local/server/apache/bin/rotatelogs /home/log/apache/checkout/access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400 +540"

    #mod-wsgi : test
    WSGIScriptAlias /test /home/service/was/test/test_app.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess test_app processes=4 threads=4 display-name=%{GROUP}
    <Directory /home/service/was/test/ >
        WSGIProcessGroup test_app
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my wsgi script, `test_App.wsgi` and `test_app.py`:

```
#test_app.wsgi 
import os, sys
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/service/was/test/')
print os 
print sys
from test_app import app as application
```

In this setting, I run test_app.py in my dev-server.

Why generate 'Target WSGI script '/home/service/was/test/test_app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.' message?

Why do not import python module installed by pip?

Comment: maybe use `shebang` in first line - ie. `#!/usr/bin/env python` ?

Comment: Apache can use different Python version than you - if you have several version installed - so it can't find `Flask` in its version.

Comment: @furas How to confirm python version in Apache server?

Comment: In `test_app.wsgi` you can add `print(sys.version)` and maybe `print(sys.path)` to see all paths to modules.